# How to unselect ol.layer.Vector programmatically

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a vector layer with markers layer in OpenLayers3

```
var iconLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: iconSource,
        style: styles.iconStyle
 });
```

Click events on the markers do some stuff and also change the markers style when selected like

```
var markerClickInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
  condition: ol.events.condition.click,
  layers:[iconLayer],
  style:styles.iconSelectedStyle
});
```

How could I deselect a selected feature programmatically (not via the default deselect behavior (e.g. clicking elsewhere on the map etc)).

Answer (score 2):

While creating `ol.interaction.Select` interaction you can specify **features** options. If this option is set all the selected features will be placed in this `ol.Collection` object. Using this `ol.Collection` you can manipulate the selected features like `clear()` or whatever. if `ol.Collection` object is cleared all the features selected are automatically deselected.

```
var featuresColl = new ol.Collection();
var markerClickInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
  condition: ol.events.condition.click,
  layers:[iconLayer],
  style:styles.iconSelectedStyle,
  features : featuresColl
});
```

Comment: what is iconLayer will this override deselect on outside map click